# Bpel boolean condition

Tags: xml, if-statement, schema, bpel

I am quite new in bpel. I strrugle with the expressing boolean in the bpel process. I have in my schema the element called "Status" type boolean. Basically if the value of "Status" is 'true' or '1' then the process executes either the Email_Order or SOA_Order sub-process, depending on the value of the element SendMode.

I wanted to created the if ealse condition for "Status" however I am not sure how should I edit the expression : $input.payload/tns:input=''

here you have the schema:

```
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Status" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element name="SendMode" type="tns:SendModeType"/>
<xsd:choice>
<xsd:element name="EmailAddress" type="tns:EmailAddressType" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element name="ServiceAddress" type="tns:ServiceAddressType" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
```

I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer depends on the WSDL and both the element form and the target namespace defined in the XSD.

Typically boolean($input.payload//myns:Status/text()) with myns bound to the target namespace of your schema should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Daniel I will try that! I just shortly paste the WSDL code.

```
<wsdl:message name="CheckStockWSOpRequest">
<wsdl:part element="xsd1:CheckStockWSRequest" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="CheckStockWSOpResponse">
<wsdl:part element="xsd1:CheckStockWSResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="checkstockPT">
<wsdl:operation name="checkStockOp">
<wsdl:input message="tns:CheckStockWSOpRequest"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:CheckStockWSOpResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```